# What does {,*/}*.* mean in Gruntfile.js

Tags: javascript, url, path, gruntjs, yeoman

Opening Gruntfile.js generated by yeoman, I see this:

```
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'images/{,*/}*.webp',
                    '{,*/}*.html',
                    'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        styles: {
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css'
        }
    },
```

What does `{,*/}*.*` mean? I can see it's trying to grab everything from the folder and I know * means any character. But I have no idea what the pattern do exactly...

Please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{,*/}*.*` is equivalent to `*/*.* OR *.*`

It is a globbing pattern to search all files but only 1 folder deep.

If you want to search the files in all the subdirectories, you can use something like `**/*.*` but it can use more CPU if the folder tree is deep.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also want to know what , and {} mean in this pattern. Also could you please write some links for references? Thank you very much!